# How prove this integral inequality $1\le \int_{0}^{2}f(x)\,dx\le 3$

Tags: inequality

Let $f(x)$ be differentiable on $[0,2]$,and such $f(0)=f(2)=1,|f'(x)|\le 1,x\in[0,2]$.

Show that

$$1\le \int_{0}^{2}f(x)\,dx\le 3.$$

I want use Taylor theorem
$$1=f(0)=f(x)+f'(x)(0-x)+f''(\xi_{1})/2\cdot x^2$$
$$1=f(1)=f(x)+f'(x)(1-x)+f''(\xi_{2})/2\cdot x^2$$

Answer (score 3):

By Taylor's theorem with just one term (you can't use 2 terms as you have no information on if $f''$ exists), for any $x\in [0,2]$ we have $$\begin{align}f(x) &= f(0) + f'(c)x \\
f(x) &= f(2) + f'(d)(x-2)\end{align}$$ for some $c,d \in [0,2]$.
The first one shows $$1-x \leq f(x) \leq 1 + x \qquad (*)$$ and the second shows $$1 +(x-2) \leq f(x) \leq 1-(x-2) \qquad$$
i.e.
$$x-1 \leq f(x) \leq 3-x. \qquad(**)$$

Now using $(*)$ shows $$1/2 \leq \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx \leq 3/2$$
and using $(**)$ shows $$1/2 \leq \int_1^2 f(x) \,dx \leq 3/2$$
then adding together gives the result.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Regarding Taylor, you don't know that $f$ is twice differentiable. Even if that is the case, you have now bounds for the second derivative.

We know that

$$
\frac{d}{dx} [f(x) - x]  = f'(x) - 1 \leq |f'(x)| -1 \leq 0.
$$

Hence, $f(x) - x \leq f(0) - 0 = 1$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. This yields

$$
\int_0^1 f(x) \,dx \leq \int_0^1 1 + x \,dx = 3/2.
$$

Similarly,

$$
\frac{d}{dx} [f(x) + x ] =f'(x) +1  \geq -|f'(x)| + 1 \geq -1+1=0.
$$

Hence, $f(x) + x \geq f(0) + 0 = 1$, which means $f(x) \geq 1-x$ for $x \in [0,1]$. Hence

$$
\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx \geq \int_0^1 1 - x\,dx = 1 - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}.
$$

Similary estimates hold for the second half $[1,2]$, which I leave to you.